# using google maps api with python

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/future-vision/google-maps-in-python-part-2-393f96196eaf) guide in starting with gmaps api and python;

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
import pandas as pd


def func():
    # Use google maps api
    gmaps.configure(api_key='MY_API_KEY')  # Fill in with your API key
    # Get the dataset
    earthquake_df = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset_as_df('earthquakes')
    # Get the locations from the data set
    locations = earthquake_df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
    # Get the magnitude from the data
    weights = earthquake_df['magnitude']
    # Set up your map
    fig = gmaps.figure()
    fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations, weights=weights))
    return fig

func()
```

been using this code from the guide (both on pychram and jupyter notebooks) but when i run the code (pychram/jupyter/terminal) I don't get the output map like in the guide.
just a nice old-fashion

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I think you are missing the last line, which is to call `fig`

Comment: sorry, you're right, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it is enabled for jupyter first by running `jupyter nbextension list`.
If you do not see `jupyter-gmaps/extension  enabled` then you need to run this line in terminal `jupyter nbextension enable --py gmaps` and then run a new jupyter notebook.

Comment: It worked! so thanks, but actually ran into the same problem with gmplot.